# php curl basic authentication as per RFC2617

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I want to post data to the url  using basic authentication as per RFC2617

```
$header = base64_encode("testindia01@test.com:india123");

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Authorization: Basic '.$header));
```

What else I need to do here, I am passing **':'** separated username and password using base64 encoding?

I am getting **401 response**, that is unauthorized where as my username and password are valid, I am able to login using them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually injecting the Authentication header, use `CURL_USERPWD` and the `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH=>CURLAUTH_BASIC` setting.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#98164

Comment: Thanks @mario, I used the same code, i am still getting the same error **status 401**

Comment: `$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "testindia01@test.com:india123"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url); `

Comment: @devel: You should leave out the SSL stuff, try just the first two lines. Otherwise use a network sniffer to debug what cURL actually sent. (Might be an outdated version.)