# How to use PHP to retrieve Wowza HTTP Providers

Tags: php, wowza

Wowza Streaming Server provides HTTP Providers for providing information about current connections and server status. They use basic HTTP authentication in the model of http://username:password@url.com:8086/connectioncounts. This will output an xml view of what's happening on the server and how many streaming connections there are.

I'm admittedly a PHP newb but I've searched through a fair amount of Stackoverflow and Google. I've tried many of the examples and so far all that is returned is nothing when trying to programmatically access the data.

I've attempted to use cURL as well use the simplexml tools. phpinfo() tells me I have all of the necessary packages to remotes work with and process urls and remote xml files. I have tested the same code with other pages like my website and it works just fine albeit my homepage doesn't use basic authentication.

Similar questions I've tried:

- [PHP Get XML from Remote URL with HTTP Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643229/php-get-xml-from-remote-url-with-http-authentication)
- [How can I read a remote XML file that uses digest authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303310/how-can-i-read-a-remote-xml-file-that-uses-digest-authentication)

Typical output looks like this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<WowzaMediaServer>
<ConnectionsCurrent>1</ConnectionsCurrent>
<ConnectionsTotal>2</ConnectionsTotal>
<ConnectionsTotalAccepted>2</ConnectionsTotalAccepted>
<ConnectionsTotalRejected>0</ConnectionsTotalRejected>
<MessagesInBytesRate>1324.0</MessagesInBytesRate>
<MessagesOutBytesRate>0.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
<VHost>
<Name>_defaultVHost_</Name>
<TimeRunning>5883.723</TimeRunning>
<ConnectionsLimit>0</ConnectionsLimit>
<ConnectionsCurrent>1</ConnectionsCurrent>
<ConnectionsTotal>2</ConnectionsTotal>
<ConnectionsTotalAccepted>2</ConnectionsTotalAccepted>
<ConnectionsTotalRejected>0</ConnectionsTotalRejected>
<MessagesInBytesRate>1324.0</MessagesInBytesRate>
<MessagesOutBytesRate>0.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
<Application>
<Name>live</Name>
<Status>loaded</Status>
<TimeRunning>5877.738</TimeRunning>
<ConnectionsCurrent>1</ConnectionsCurrent>
<ConnectionsTotal>2</ConnectionsTotal>
<ConnectionsTotalAccepted>2</ConnectionsTotalAccepted>
<ConnectionsTotalRejected>0</ConnectionsTotalRejected>
<MessagesInBytesRate>1324.0</MessagesInBytesRate>
<MessagesOutBytesRate>0.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
<ApplicationInstance>
<Name>_definst_</Name>
<TimeRunning>5877.622</TimeRunning>
<ConnectionsCurrent>1</ConnectionsCurrent>
<ConnectionsTotal>2</ConnectionsTotal>
<ConnectionsTotalAccepted>2</ConnectionsTotalAccepted>
<ConnectionsTotalRejected>0</ConnectionsTotalRejected>
<MessagesInBytesRate>1324.0</MessagesInBytesRate>
<MessagesOutBytesRate>0.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
<Stream>
<Name>mystream.mp4</Name>
<SessionsFlash>0</SessionsFlash>
<SessionsCupertino>0</SessionsCupertino>
<SessionsSanJose>0</SessionsSanJose>
<SessionsSmooth>0</SessionsSmooth>
<SessionsRTSP>0</SessionsRTSP>
<SessionsMPEGDash>0</SessionsMPEGDash>
<SessionsTotal>0</SessionsTotal>
</Stream>
</ApplicationInstance>
</Application>
</VHost>
</WowzaMediaServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default HTTP Authentication for wowza media server is digest.

But you can change it to basic in VHost.xml in conf folder.

Just change admin-digest

to be admin-basic